# How to replace a value by index in a list within a data frame

Tags: r, indexing, replace, bioinformatics

Hope someone can help me out here. I am pretty much a newbie with R, and now I'm stuck..
I am working with NGS sequencing, more specifically, regarding this particular problem, trying to prepare a definition file (gene rod) for genes needed for generating an estimate of coverage. Very specific format, unfortunately.
The definition file (a data frame) includes UTR's, and I need to get rid of the non-coding regions.
Definition file (test_data) looks like this:

```
  cdsStart   cdsEnd exonCount                 exonStarts                   exonEnds
1 10223907 10226228         3 10223907,10225271,10226146, 10224072,10225336,10226228,
2 64014978 64015261         2          64014587,64015159,          64015044,64015405,
3 10994492 10995036         3 10987702,10994465,10994988, 10987737,10994726,10995081,
```

And this is how it should be after transformation:

```
  cdsStart   cdsEnd exonCount                 exonStarts                   exonEnds
1 10223907 10226228         3 10223907,10225271,10226146, 10224072,10225336,10226228,
2 64014978 64015261         2          64014978,64015159,          64015044,64015261,
3 10994492 10995036         3          10994492,10994988,          10994726,10995036,
```

Within each line of this data frame there is a list or vector of exon start positions (exonStarts) and another one for exon end positions (exonEnds). Also a single value is given for cdsStart and for cdsEnd.
If exonStarts is less than cdsStart I need to replace the exonStarts value by the cdsStart value. Likewise, if exonEnds is larger then cdsEnd I need to replace it  with cdsEnd..
In the example above (disregarding the header) line 1 needs no corrections.
Line 2 needs to have first index of exonStarts replaced by cdsStart AND last index of exonEnds replaced by cdsEnd.
Line 3, the first two exons are non-coding (start position is less than cdsStart), so I need to get rid of index 1 of exonStarts, replace index 2 with cdsStart, replace last index of exonEnds with cdsEnd and get rid of first index of exonEnds.

Grateful for any help :-)

What I have tried is, in a for loop, split exonStarts (same for exonEnds);

```
i <- 3
test_tx_start <- str_split(test_data[i, ]$exonStarts[[1]], pattern=',')
```

then conditionally replace:

```
if (test_tx_start[[1]][1] < test_data[3, ]$cdsStart) {
  test_tx_start <- replace(test_tx_start[[1]], 1, test_data[3, ]$cdsStart)
```

It's getting very complicated and slow, I bet there are better ways of doing this operation!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your data in a more reproducible-friendly format (ie, `dput(test_data)`) and also provide the desired output of `test_data`? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could provide the columns as vectors using `Map`, `strsplit` at the comma, subset by start and end using `>=` and `<=` operators, `c`oncatenate start or end, make `unique`, and make `data.frame`s out of it that you `rbind`.

```
with(dat, Map(\(v, w, x, y, z) {
  y <- as.integer(strsplit(y, ',')[[1]])
  z <- as.integer(strsplit(z, ',')[[1]])
  data.frame(v, w, x, 
             sprintf('%s,', paste(collapse=',', unique(c(v, y[y >= v & y <= w])))), 
             sprintf('%s,', paste(collapse=',', unique(c(z[z >= v & z <= w], w))))) |> 
    setNames(names(dat))
}, cdsStart, cdsEnd, exonCount, exonStarts, exonEnds)) |>
  do.call(what='rbind')
#   cdsStart   cdsEnd exonCount                  exonStarts                    exonEnds
# 1 10223907 10226228         3 10223907,10225271,10226146, 10224072,10225336,10226228,
# 2 64014978 64015261         2          64014978,64015159,          64015044,64015261,
# 3 10994492 10995036         3          10994492,10994988,          10994726,10995036,
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(cdsStart = c(10223907L, 64014978L, 10994492L), 
    cdsEnd = c(10226228L, 64015261L, 10995036L), exonCount = c(3L, 
    2L, 3L), exonStarts = c("10223907,10225271,10226146,", "64014587,64015159,", 
    "10987702,10994465,10994988,"), exonEnds = c("10224072,10225336,10226228,", 
    "64015044,64015405,", "10987737,10994726,10995081,")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That worked !! I'm amazed.. 9 lines!!!

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to figure out how this works, that will not be easy, I am sure.